# Replacing a character of size length > 2 in linked list

Tags: arrays, string, list, linked-list, character

I have a question regarding replacing a character in a linked list. If I have a linked list that contains a node value to be changed by a string of length greater than 2, how would I implement doing this iteratively? Here is my logic:

```
if (node->data == key)
   ptr = node->next
   node->data = string_ptr->data
   node->link = string_ptr->link
```

then I would run through the node->link until I reach the end of the node and then connect

```
node->link = ptr
```

thus bringing me back to original linked list.

What I am trying to achieve is this:

say I have the word : `a -> n -> a -> d`
the key is a and the string to replace the key is `A -> N -> D`
Thus I should get : `A -> N -> D -> n -> A -> N -> D -> d`

But I get: `A -> n -> A -> d`

EDIT: here is the struct used:

```
struct node 

{ 

   char data; 

   struct node *next; 

} node;
```

Sorry for the mess.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that each node in your linked list is a character? And the linked list as a whole represents a work/string?

Comment: Yes each node in the linked list contain a pointer to a character and the a link to the next node.                                   Side note: BUT in the function (node *head, char key, char *str) the string can have a length of more than 1 thus it contains more than one character.

Comment: Yes it can be assumed that the linked list represents as a whole string. Basically the function attempts to change the linked list from have something like: apple to Snapple or Big to Bigger. In the end result it is still a word. My only problem is that when I try to insert a string greater than length of 2 it only prints the first character of the string. I believe my problem is not being able to use for ( ; node->link != NULL; node = node->next) to get to the end of the linked list, i.e. implementing this for loop causes an infinite loop.

Comment: may I see the struct used to represent the list?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following sequence of nodes:

```
a -> n -> a -> d
```

And you want to replace `a` with `A -> N -> D`, for every occurence of a you need to create three nodes: `A`, `N` and `D` for each occurence of the `a` element.
The code should look something like this:

```
struct node *tmp, *next_bak;
char char_to_replace = a;
char string[] = "AND";

while(node->next != NULL) {
    if (node->data == char_to_replace) {
        next_bak = node->next;
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
        tmp->data = string[0];

        for(int i = 1; i < strlen(string); i++) {
            tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
            tmp->next->data = string[i];
            tmp = tmp->next;    
        }

        tmp->next = next_bak;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing here is creating three list elements every time the character is matched, and replacing the Node that contains the matched character with the new list.